# QGIS Error Adding WMS Layer

Tags: qgis, wms

I want to add a WMS-Layer to QGIS.
If I try it, I get the following message:

> "Antwort nicht verstanden. Der wms-Provider sagte:
>   Eigenschaften-Abfrage gescheitert: Connection closed"

It's a protected WMS, using https and basic authentication.
I have no problems to use the WMS-Layer in ArcGIS. There is no proxy.
Does anybody have an idea what's going wrong or where I can look for?
I'm using QGIS Desktop 2.0.1.
I can load and visualize other WMS-Services in QGIS (they use http).

Comment: You could try to access the getCapabilites using e.g. Firefox and paste them here so we can try to figure out if there is an incompatibility there. Do you know which WMS server software is running at the other end?

Comment: Maybe related to http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11540